# infinity products of real numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

are there any rules to determine if a infinity product $\prod\limits_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n$ converges?

1.it is easy to see that if $a_n>1$ for each $n$,(or $1>a_n>0$),and $\prod\limits_{n\in\mathbb N}b_n$ converges,where $b_n>a_n$ ($0<b_n<a_n$) then $\prod\limits_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n$ converges.

2.by Leibniz thorem we can get that if $a_n>a_{n+1}>1$ for each $n$,and $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=1$ then $\Pi_{n\in \mathbb N}a_n^{-1^n}$ converges.

am I right about 1,2, and are there any more ways to determine the convergence?

Comment: I think you can make the logarithm and then consider the normal series. Hope this helps.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_products

Comment: In 2., one must assume that $a_n\to1$.

Comment: `\Pi_{n\in\mathbb N}` $\to$ `\prod\limits_{n\in\mathbb N}`.

Comment: what you are saying is that we can answer the question of a product by a question about a sum, and we know how to deal with sums.is there any converge test for products,which is simple, so that you would test a sum with that product test?